# Merge two table and pick data based on table order

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to merge 2021 tbl with 2020 table. If the same record(id) is common in two tables then i go for 2021 table, if the id is not present in 2021 then go for 2020 and if the id is not present in 021 and in 020 then 020 record is selected. I tried to address this using coalesce but it's not helping. Any suggestions on improving this situation.

```
2021_table

|num| name | location | age | gender | foundation | relation | email |
| ---|------|----------|-----|--------|------------|----------|--------
| 1 | ally |  texas   | 55  | F | NA  | mom | null          |
|2  | rick |  newyork | 45  | M | NA  | dad | rick@pronet.com|
|3  | macy |  cali    | 66  | F | EY  | na  | macy@yahoo.com|
|8A | steve|  ark     | 39  | M | JJ  | xyz | stev@gmail.com|
 

 2020_table
 
| num| name | location | gender | org | status | descent |
| ----|------|----------|-----|--------|-----|--------|-------|
|1  | ally |  texas   |  F  |  |  |
|2  | r    |  newyork |  M  |  |  |
|78 | naomy|  NULL    |  F  |  |  |
|B12| romy | CO       |  M  |  |  |
 

Output_table:

| num| name | location | age | gender | foundation | relation | email |
| ----|------|----------|-----|--------|------------|----------|---|
| 1  | ally |  texas   | 55  | F | NA  | mom | null           |
| 2  | rick |  newyork | 45  | M | NA  | dad | rick@pronet.com|
|3   | macy |  cali    | 66  | F | EY  | na  | macy@yahoo.com |
|8A  | steve|  ark     | 39  | M | JJ  | xyz | stev@gmail.com |
| 78 | naomy|  NULL    | 30  | F |     |     |                |
| B12| romy | CO       | 69  | M |     |     |                |
```

Comment: Look at a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. I *assume* the reason you want to do this is to fix your design as you shouldn't be storing data for separate years in separate tables.

Comment: Why do you have different tables? I'd consider one common table, perhaps with a year column.

Comment: both are different tables, different genres. the intention is to match the records and pick the most relevant ones based on the table year

Comment: *"both are different tables, different genres. "* So you have different tables for different years and genres? That's even worse. There should one table, and it should have a column for the year and genre.

Comment: i get you, but right now i can only make use of what i have. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` and `exists`:

```
select t2021.num, t2021.name, t2021.location, t2021.age, t2021.gender, t2021.foundation, t2021.relation, t2021.email
from table_2021 t2021
union all
select t2020.num, t2020.name, t2020.location, t2020.age, t2020.gender, NULL, NULL, NULL
from table_2020 t2020
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_2021 t2021
                  where t2021.num = t2020.num
                 );
```

Note that having two tables with the same columns is usually an indication that you have a problem with your data model.  I would recommend putting all the data in a single table, with an additional column for the year.

Comment: i tried select coalesce( t1. name, t2.name ) as name, coalesce on the all cols, from t1 full outer join t2 on t1.id= t2.id. What is your opinion about this approach?

Comment: I'm not able to apply this query cos i'm getting an error stating that 'Union operator must have an equal number of expression in theri target lists'

Comment: @New_here . . . I see.  The table structure is not the same.  I adjusted the answer.

Comment: Sir one doubt...how does this query prioritizes tbl_2021 over tbl_2020? Could you pl explain

Comment: @New_here . . . It selects everything from 2021.  Only ids not in 2021 are taken from 2020.  Voila!  Prioritization.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The query below should meet the rules stated:

- if id is common in two tables then go for 2021 table,
- if the id is not present in 2021 then go for 2020 and
- if the id is not present in 021 and in 020 then 020 record is selected

The tables are not identical, so I set NULLs for the 2020 table for columns not existing in the 2021 table.  Empty string ( '' ) also works.

```
SELECT num, name , location , age , gender , foundation , relation , email FROM t2021

UNION 

SELECT num, name , location , age , gender , NULL foundation , NULL relation , NULL email FROM t2020
WHERE num NOT IN  ( SELECT num FROM t2021 )
```

Comment: thanks. If i use Union all instead of UNION then will my output contain duplicate records as well?

Comment: No.  Duplicates are removed by the NOT IN clause in the second query.  I used UNION because it does an auto sort. But, you could test UNION ALL and find out.  If you found this helpful, please mark as Answer and upvote.  Thank you.